# Ingress routing to different services and with different paths to same service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 5000
      paths:
      - path: /api/tasks/.*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: tasks-service
          servicePort: 5004
      paths:
      - path: /api/.*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service
          servicePort: 5001
```

I'm intending to load the frontend by default then, use the other paths for loading other services. I would like to get the total tasks count from `/api/tasks/total_count` and raise new task from `/api/tasks/raise`. At the same time, I would like to login using `/api/auth/login/` and view other users with `/api/users/list` both served with the um-service.
The above configuration only returns the default path of the last service which is the um-service.
How do I configure so that web loads by default, then either `/api/auth/login` or `/api/users/list` are routed to the um-service and `/api/tasks/` is also routed to the tasks service? Kindly advice

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to achieve that result:

```
$ curl <MY_DOMAIN>/api/auth/login
um-service
$ curl <MY_DOMAIN>/api/users/list
um-service
$ curl <MY_DOMAIN>/api/tasks/
tasks-service
$ curl <MY_DOMAIN>/
web-service
```

You almost did everything right, but `paths` should only be given once

Try this configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /api/tasks/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: tasks-service
          servicePort: 5004
      - path: /api/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service
          servicePort: 5001
```

Comment: You are awesome sir!!